# How can i move the image object smoothly when I am using accelerometer in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, object, accelerometer

In my app I am moving the ball according to the accelerometer movements but the ball not moved smoothly .I need to move the ball smoothly on view.How can i?

I used below statements by searching on google.but i didn't get the smooth object

```
delta.x = 0.01 * delta.x + (1.0 - 0.01) * acceleration.x;
delta.y = 0.01 * delta.y + (1.0 - 0.01) * acceleration.y;
```

Comment: Write your CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation animation to get a smooth animated movements. You can use basic UIViewAnimation block for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    point = CGPointMake(34*acceleration.x, -20*acceleration.y);
    image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x+point.x,image.center.y);

}
```

Comment: I used this code but i didnt get the smooth movement for ball                                   delta.x = 4*acceleration.x ;
    delta.y = -2*acceleration.y ;
 rotate = rotate + (2.0f * ((float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) - 1.0f) * .01; //random number between -1, 1

    scrollingBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(scrollingBtn.transform, rotate);
 scrollingBtn.center = CGPointMake(scrollingBtn.center.x + ballVelocity.x+delta.x,scrollingBtn.center.y + ballVelocity.y+(delta.y * -1));      Ball is bounces on the bar image i need to give the smooth movement how can i?

Answer (score 0):

use

> [UIView beginAniations:@"AnimaionName" context:nil];
>
> [UIView setAnimationDuration: 2.0f];
>
> imageView.frame = CGRectMake(,,,);
>
> [UIView commitAnimation];

This will provide smooth movement